# What method does QGIS Merge Rasters tool use?

Tags: qgis, raster, merge, mosaic

I am trying to merge rasters in QGIS and want to set a priority order for merging so that the values from the highest priority raster are used in overlap areas (the “FIRST” merge/mosaic method, I believe).

Does anyone know what the merge method is for the QGIS tool under Vector -> Miscellaneous -> Merge?  I have not found documentation for the method, but it is clear that it is combining the files in some way other than just taking values from the first loaded raster.

Is the SAGA Mosaic Raster Layers my best alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For merging rasters, QGIS use the script [gdal_merge](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/GdalMerge) (Python script)

```
gdal_merge.py raster1.tif raster2.tif raster3.tif -o merged.tif
```

Merge method is for the QGIS tool under Vector -> Miscellaneous -> Merge merge vector layers, as its name indicates

Comment: So looking at the link you posted, it looks like it is stacking the opposite of what I thought.   The explanation of the gdal_merge script  says:   "The last image in the input line comes out on top of the finished image stack."    I had also tried the GDAL merge tool and saw that the outcome was at least visually the same as the QGIS tool, thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 3):

The GRASS `r.patch` from the Processing Toolbox also does the work.
I could not manage to merge two rasters due to some file name issues and who knows what else, but with r.patch everything went smooth, specially the multiple selection form the rasters in the layer tree.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have gdal_merge in 
Menu >> Raster >> Miscellaneous >> Merge..

Here is a [training page](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/processing/cutting_merging.html?highlight=merge%20raster) in the QGIS Help file.