# Mix two raster files with different land mass in QGIS or R

Tags: qgis, raster, r

I need to mix two raster files (tif-Format) in QGIS or R.

- File 1 is a DEM of recent times.
- File 2 contains only information about land mass and sea level of 40.000 years ago.
- File 1 & 2 have the same extent and cell size.

How can I mix both files in R or QGIS to get a result where the most part is of File 1 (the DEM because its land mass) but when the current land mass ends, it should be extended by file 2?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Select only one software and include what have you done

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What method does QGIS Merge Rasters tool use?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188806/what-method-does-qgis-merge-rasters-tool-use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With QGIS raster Calculator tool, you can try the following expression:

```
(file1@1 > 0) * file1@1 + (file1@1 <= 0) * file2@1
```

This will fill the output raster with `file1` values if they are positive, and `file2` values else.